# How to use one escaped argument with the Mysql Python connector

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, python-3.3, mysql-5.6

I am using the official MySQL Python connector, but the [example in the tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html) does not work for me with the specific query I am using.

```
sql = "SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = %s"
cursor.execute(sql,('testdb')) # This throws an error, sql syntax error near %s
```

The code `cursor.execute("SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Db = 'testdb'")` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), the second argument to `execute` should be either a dictionary or a tuple. 1-element tuple *must* have an extra coma after the element in order to not be confused with a parenthesized expression:

```
cursor.execute(sql,('testdb',))
#                           ^
```